# I want to improve pentaho performace for data loading

Tags: pentaho-data-integration

I have 4 million records that needs daily load of data from source to target and we are doing truncate everyday. It takes like 9 hours as there are like 10 tables doing 4 million records data loading every day. 
Could you please tell me how do i improve the performance. Thanks

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: My Source is Oracle and Destination is MySQL

Comment: I know this solution and has already implemented but no use and I even increased number of copies to 4.

Comment: Ok. Then I can't really think of any other way in Pentaho to make it faster. What about the bulk loader?

Comment: I tried MySQL bulk loader but i am getting some error in creating mkfifo file on the Linux server as we can only use MySQL bulk loader in Linux environment

Comment: Hello Nikhil, where do i add the settings useServerPrepStmts=false
rewriteBatchedStatements=true
useCompression=true inside the pentaho server for the MySQL Pentaho Admin Console to pick up the settings?

Comment: In the Database connections window, you will see "options" on the left side of the window. You can enter these parameters over there.

Comment: i want to make changes in the BI server, as we have database connections configured in the server. So Please tell me how to do it. Do i have to edit any JDBC file. If so what is the path for it. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure. See if this helps: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.1/0H0/060/010/030/020

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Use the MY SQL bulk loader step available in PDI. It will definitely make the data loading faster.
2. Speed can be boosted by using some simple JDBC-connection setting.

   ```
   useServerPrepStmts=false
   rewriteBatchedStatements=true
   useCompression=true
   ```

These options should be entered in PDI at the connection. Double click the connection go to Options and set these values.

Used together, `useServerPrepStmts=false` and `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` will “fake” batch inserts on the client. Specifically, the insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO t (c1,c2) VALUES ('One',1);
INSERT INTO t (c1,c2) VALUES ('Two',2);
INSERT INTO t (c1,c2) VALUES ('Three',3);
```

will be rewritten into:

```
`INSERT INTO t (c1,c2) VALUES ('One',1),('Two',2),('Three',3`);
```

The third option `useCompression=true` compresses the traffic between the client and the MySQL server.

Finally you can increase the number of copies of the output step to 2 so that there are two threads inserting into the database.

Hope it helps!

Reference (Option 2): https://anonymousbi.wordpress.com